# google-api-php-client - Get File Contents

Tags: php, file, methods, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Using the following code:

```
// get the file contents

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$fileId = 'The File ID';

try {
  echo 'try part <br>';
  $result3 = $service->files->get($fileId);

  echo 'Contents: ' . $result3->getContent().'<br>';
  echo "Title: " . $result3->getTitle() . '<br>';
  echo "Description: " . $result3->getDescription() . '<br>';
  echo "MIME type: " . $result3->getMimeType() . '<br>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
};
```

Everything works except for this line:

```
echo 'Contents: ' . $result3->getContent().'<br>';
```

In the **drive.php** file in the API, there is a `getContent()` function, but it's not working.  How do I get the content out of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the Google documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get you'll see that there are two forms of the Get method. The default fetches the metadata (eg. title, description, etc), whereas `alt=media` fetches the content. Alternatively, you can also fetch the content via the downloadUrl property. I don't know if the PHP library exposes the `alt=media` option (I don't like libraries), but the downloadUrl approach has an example on the page I linked, just scroll down and click "php"

Comment: Looks like that second option uses the API `Google_Http_Request` Class.  After looking at the `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` Class code, I realized it only gets the metadata.